# How to write this layout in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

The TextView icon is not a Compound Drawable since the bottom line doesnt cover it.

How to define a layout like this where beside each text is an icon?[image]

I just see ugly to add so much ViewGroups in the same view just to have the icon because there will be a lot of text input in the view.

Comment: Which icon are you talking about? The phone icon?

Comment: Just add a TextView, ImageView, EditText and a Spinner to a horizontal layout and assign proper weight to each to achieve this.

Comment: @Shamas Question updated

Comment: @Aradhna Question Updated

Comment: @danielgomezrico the only way i see this happening is by adding an ImageView besied each text. Make a <selector> xml with black and blue versions of the icon.

Comment: @Aradhna question updated

Comment: @danielgomezrico you can also make a view with the image and the text and then use this view and make you layout in other xml. That way you wont have to write the code again and again.

Comment: `The TextView icon is not a Compound Drawable since the bottom line doesnt cover it.` This isn't necessarily true. You can have a 9 patch as the background AND a compound drawable on the left.

Comment: I suddenly have a doubt: are you talking about an **EditText** or about a  **TextView**? Because they are **different beasts**. An EditText automatically adds a line under the text, while a TextView does not.

Answer (score 0):

use drawableLeft property of textview to set an icon with your text, it will create a single view with your icon and your text.

```
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
 android:drawableBottom="@drawable/icon_line"
```

Comment: Off topic. The question asks how to add a graphical line under the text AND a drawable on the left.

Comment: @Bob , If you dont use any background for edittext , it will automatically provide a line under that edittext.

Comment: If we were talking about an **EditText**, this would be true. But the OP asked for a **TextView**.

Comment: Yeah  i know the difference. Sorry i forgot we were talking about textview. We can use drawableBottom and set an image of line with that textview to make it work.

Comment: Which is what I affirm in my first comment.

Comment: We can use both properties, drawableLeft and drawableBottom to achieve this thing.

Comment: Or a 9 patch background + a drawable left. Or just a single 9 patch with a fixed part on the left (the icon) and the rest is stretchable. As usual, there are several ways to do the same thing.